# Find the base potential

Tags: voltage, transistors, base

Question "a" says "find the base potential Vb", and I can't do it :(. All the resistors are given above (you don't need to understand french, don't worry)
Could someone help me please, I would appreciate it !!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an NPN transistor the base needs to be at a higher potential than the emitter in order for the transistor to conduct. (basic bias condition). Since there's no information about leakage or anything else the transistor is turned OFF.

With no current through the transistor the voltage at the emitter is 0V. No current can flow into the base so there is no voltage drop across (Rx and R) leaving the base at 0V.